# Yii2 Natural sorting Text+Number

Tags: sorting, yii2

I have a MySQL table with a field **name** that contains not only text, but also a number. I sort by **name**:

`->orderBy(['name' => SORT_ASC])`

...
ALTAMURA 7
ALTAMURA 8
ANSEDONIA 1
**ANSEDONIA 10

ANSEDONIA 11

ANSEDONIA 12**

ANSEDONIA 2
ANSEDONIA 3
...
ANSEDONIA 9

But I want the list to be sorted not only alphabetically but also by the numbers inside the name:

...
ALTAMURA 7
ALTAMURA 8
ANSEDONIA 1
ANSEDONIA 2
ANSEDONIA 3
...
ANSEDONIA 9
ANSEDONIA 10
ANSEDONIA 11
ANSEDONIA 12

If it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. To do this, you'll need to use a quite special kind of sorting called "natural sorting". SQL does not include natural sorting inherently but we can simulate it. In MySQL for example, you can use CONVERT(column, UNSIGNED INTEGER) to sort your mixed string/integer field. This implicit conversion extracts the numeric part and sorts it as a number.
Here's an example of how it might look in your case:

```
->orderBy([
   new \yii\db\Expression('CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", -1) AS UNSIGNED)')
])
```

For PostgreSQL, you can simulate natural sorting using regular expressions to separate the numeric part of the field.
Here's how you might do it:

```
->orderBy([
    new \yii\db\Expression("substring(name, '^[a-zA-Z]+')"),
    new \yii\db\Expression("CAST(substring(name, '[0-9]+$') AS INTEGER)"),
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now it's not exactly what I need.

ALTAMURA 1
ANSEDONIA 1
ALTAMURA 2
ANSEDONIA 2
...

Comment: But I need ALTAMURA 1 ALTAMURA 2 ... ALTAMURA 8 ANSEDONIA 1
ANSEDONIA 2 ... ANSEDONIA 12

Comment: If you want to sort by the numerical part of each record first and then sort by the alphabetical part. Here's how you can adjust the code:  
->orderBy([
    new \yii\db\Expression("CAST(substring(name, '[0-9]+$') AS INTEGER)"),
    new \yii\db\Expression("substring(name, '^[a-zA-Z]+')"),
])

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specify that I'm using MySQL

Comment: for "ALTAMURA 1 ANSEDONIA 1 ALTAMURA 2 ANSEDONIA 2" use ->orderBy([
            new \yii\db\Expression('CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", -1) AS UNSIGNED)'),
            new \yii\db\Expression('SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", 1)'),
        ]), for "ALTAMURA 1 ALTAMURA 2 ANSEDONIA 1  ANSEDONIA 2" use ->orderBy([
            new \yii\db\Expression('SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", 1)'),
            new \yii\db\Expression('CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", -1) AS UNSIGNED)'),
        ])